# OSX terminal text editing trick for a big file (over 10GB)

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, text-editor, large-data

I have text files in the rage of 10-50GB.   I need to edit the first several lines of these files as follows;

Original;

```
>Aura head -n 2  042319_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq.recovered 
==> 042319_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq.recovered <==
9�C�{a��e�T�l1�{jz7?\^tZ[1�Wvcb���]zj�\,����~
zT'zT'zT'zT'zT'zT'zT'zT'zT'zT'zTfŌȊ���@hYM�rkdt�t?��av��B�,KII9]�Hϛ�[�ada[�SY�o��|>K�H���k��%���'
                                                                                                 �LDTM&Ãd�XQ@A00165:69:HKJ3YDMXX:1:1101:4390:1266 1:N:0:CATGAACA
AGTTAGCTCACCATGATGAAACAAGACT
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@A00165:69:HKJ3YDMXX:1:1101:4896:1266 1:N:0:CATGAACA
TATCTTGTCACGATACTCAACATGTGGA
+
FFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFF:FFFF
@A00165:69:HKJ3YDMXX:1:1101:6307:1266 1:N:0:CATGAACA
```

Desired output;

```
>Aura head -n 2  042319_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq.recovered 
==> 042319_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq.recovered <==
@A00165:69:HKJ3YDMXX:1:1101:4390:1266 1:N:0:CATGAACA
AGTTAGCTCACCATGATGAAACAAGACT
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@A00165:69:HKJ3YDMXX:1:1101:4896:1266 1:N:0:CATGAACA
TATCTTGTCACGATACTCAACATGTGGA
+
FFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFF:FFFF
@A00165:69:HKJ3YDMXX:1:1101:6307:1266 1:N:0:CATGAACA
```

I tried to do this by nano but it takes for long to load the entire gigabytes of file.  I tired to split files by `split` but merged files have corrupted lines for some reasons.  I'd appreciate any pointers or tricks for this.

Updated:

Top two lines look as though they are a part of a file header but there is no binary text file headers in this file.  So I guess I am lucky.  On the other hand this is not a static text.  The length and content of lines differ in each files.

Comment: is that "sub-header" with the glyphs etc the same in each file? Or are you really lucky and is the `@A00165:69:HKJ3YDMXX:1:1101:4390:1266` portion the same in each file? Pluease update your Q with this info rather than reply in comments.

Comment: We need to know 1) if this is information that changes in each file and in each of the 2 positions in questions OR is there static text 2) If static text then don't waste time trying to match it with a regex, just delete the lines and then add back the static text you need.

Comment: Use a *nix process group to rebuild the file, something like `{ sed -N '1,2pq' file ;  cat staticTextfile ; sed -n '5,$p' file ; } > newVersionOfFile`. WORK with a small sample file until you think it is working as needed! Confirm that `newVersionOfFile` is good before renaming it as `file`. This is why you need duplicate space available on your drive. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter,  thanks for the suggestion.   Could you help me come up with another sed script ?   I need to delete any characters that are in front of "@" such as in '��XQ@A00165:69:HKJ3YDMXX:1:1101:14407:2049......'  to '@A00165:69:HKJ3YDMXX:1:1101:14407:2049' .  I've been manually deleting these line by line but there are some many of them.  Ii really appreciate if you could show me the example sed script.  Thanks.

Comment: @shellter, I tried this, gsed 's/^.*@//' but did not work.

Comment: @shellter, �� was the issue.  I had to convert these non-ASCII characters to sed readable first and then I could fire gsed 's/^.*@//', as follows;  gsed  -n 'l0' | gsed 's/.*@//'  This deletes @ also.  I have to use something else.

Comment: Hmm. "This deletes @ also, I have to use something else".  Just put the @ back in, i.e. `gsed 's/.*@/@/` . Also I don't understand how your example `gsed -n 'l0' | gsed 's/.*@//'` example could work. What is providing input to the first `gsed` in that pipeline? Either `cat file | gsed ...|gsed ...` OR `gsed .... file | gsed ...`, right? You're getting close to solving your problem! I'd recommend updating your Q above with your best attempt to solve the problem. I'll  look at it when I can, and other hungry `sed`ers may pickup your Q and give you the help you need. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorporating @shellter comments and help,  the easiest script to get rid of non-ASCII junks and get the desired output that I came up with was following;

```
gsed -n 'l0' testfile | gsed 's/.*@/@/' |  gsed '1,2d' | gsed 's/[$]//g'
```

I use brew install gnu `sed` (gsed) instead of OSX's BSD `sed`.